# What Chrome does instantly, Firefox takes 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, performance

Currently, I am creating a program that will turn source code into highlighted HTML-like text.  When I tested it, though, I found some strange results.  On Chrome, the program will parse 1000 lines of source almost instantaneously.  Firefox, however, takes 30 seconds to parse the same 1000 lines.  And, ironically enough, IE10 only takes 18 seconds.

Now, I understand that different browsers implement javascript differently and that Chrome tends to be faster, but I do not understand why it is taking Firefox over 30 times longer.  I ran a raw while-loop test of 10,000,000,000 operations on each, and it took FF 14 seconds and Chrome 12.  Therefore, I am inclined to believe that somewhere in my code is something that takes Firefox an abnormally long time to accomplish; I've done research, but nothing I've found so far would indicate the large discrepancy I am seeing.

So, does anyone have any suggestions as to what may be causing this?  I've posted the problem area of the code below (commenting this portion out causes both browsers to parse instantaneously).  `start` and `end` are both regular expressions; `istream` is where the source code is coming from, and `ostream` is where parsed code goes to.  `istream.read()` calls the String slice() method.  Finally, this function is called many many times throughout the program.

```
function(buffer, istream, ostream){
    if(start.test(istream.content)){
        buffer = istream.read();
        ostream.write('[[span class="' + type + '"]]' + buffer);
        do{
            /* Special Cases */
            if(end.test(ostream.content + istream.peek()) && (istream.peek() == "\n" || istream.peek() == " " || istream.peek() == "\t")){
                include = true;
                break;
            }
            else if(istream.peek() == "\n"){
                istream.read();
                ostream.write('[[/span]][[/span]]\n[[span class="line"]][[span class="' + type + '"]]');
                continue;
            }
            else if(istream.peek() == "\t"){
                istream.read();
                ostream.write("@<&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;>@");
                continue;
            }
            else if(istream.peek() == " "){
                istream.read();
                ostream.write("@<&#160;>@");
                continue;
            }
            ostream.write(istream.read());
        } while(!istream.isEmpty() && !end.test(ostream.content));

        if(include || istream.isEmpty())
            ostream.write('[[/span]]');
        else{
            var ending = ostream.content.length-1;
            while(!end.test(ostream.content.substr(ending)))
                --ending;
            istream.content = ostream.content.substr(ending) + istream.content;
            ostream.content = ostream.content.substring(0, ending) + '[[/span]]';
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, and if you have any queries as to how certain aspects of this are implemented, I will oblige.  Thanks in advance.

Definition of istream and ostream objects:

```
function IOstream(init){
    this.content = init;

    this.read = function(){
        var tmp = this.content.charAt(0);
        this.content = this.content.slice(1);
        return tmp;
    };
    this.peek = function(){  return this.content.charAt(0); };
    this.write = function(str){  this.content += str; };
    this.isEmpty = function(){  return this.content.length == 0; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the REs look like (`start` and `end`)?

Comment: Where does ostream.write go? To a string or directly to the DOM, etc?

Comment: Probably not the cause, but one quick thing to change would be to move the multiple `istream.peek()` calls to a single call before your `do` statement.

Comment: In my experience FireFox is the slowest browser. I've worked in several projects and FireFox has always been noticeably slower than IE and Chrome throughout several years and versions. While Chrome tends to be faster in most cases, sometimes IE is capable to notoriously outperform Chrome, but in my all my years of experience I can't remember FireFox outperforming IE and of course I'm pretty sure I never saw it outperforming Chrome.

Comment: @DemetriusAmadeus That adds little to a question dealing with performance timings many (many, many, many) magnitudes apart.

Comment: `start` and `end` are relatively simple; an example of `start` is `/^\/\*/`, and an example of `end` is `/\*\/$/`.  The ostream.write() concatenates a string.

Comment: @Ardeol Concatenates like `str = str + newStr`? What if `ostream.write` is replaced with a NOP function - is FF still beaten horribly?

Comment: It actually uses `+=`, if it makes a difference.  Turns out eliminating ostream.write() was tough since it was critical to the function of the loop.  After replacing it with a simple counter that iterates the loop 10 times each call of the function, it now takes FF 26 seconds and Chrome a little over 1.  Therefore it seems like the act of concatenating may be a contributing factor, but something else is going on.  I would like to think it is simply the raw number of times the loop is run, but the while-loop test I performed indicated that FF and Chrome should be similar, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: It is an absolute minimum for questions like this to provide the version numbers of the browsers you tested on.  What was your Firefox version?

Comment: I apologize; I'm using the latest major versions of each of Chrome and FF (31 and 25 respectively), and as stated, I was using IE10.

Comment: @user2864740 FireFox is simply many (many, many, many) magnitudes slower than Chrome. This is obviously a design flaw in the FireFox's Javascript VM so there's very little you can do about it.

Comment: Well chrome runs on V8 Js Engine, which is the engine run by NodeJs. It's clearly faster than all the other browsers when it comes to runninc js code. What V8 basically does is parsing JS code to machine code. The performance difference can be seen on objects and mainly on object's properties lookup. V8 dynamically creates hidden classes behind the scenes so an object has it's own class and when added a property to it, it's class is changed to a newer one which includes the new property, and it does so on the fly  (but note that the old class it's still maintained).

Comment: Here is a link to V8's design https://developers.google.com/v8/design . What I'm trying to say is that, if you iterate many many times through your while loop, in the function, and at every iteration you have numerous property lookups, the performance gap becomes bigger and bigger. Because V8 does the thing with it's hidden classes, will find the property in notime, whereas FF will have to search for it every time.

Comment: You can try this: Take all object properties used in your while loop and declare as local variables at very beginning of the function. Then iterate thgrough your while loop using those variables. Try to reduce the property lookup as possible as you can. Like this you should come close, I think, to chrome's performance. Now please explain me why didn't I added those 3 comments as a single answer... ?

Comment: Do you have Firebug / the Firefox debugger enabled? Firebug especially tends to slow things down MUCH more than equivalent debuggers in other browsers.

Comment: @DemetriusAmadeus See [Order of Magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude), such that you can participate meaningfully. This question is about a specific situation in which the performance is "not comparable". Please stop trying to derail it.

Comment: I have Firebug installed, but it isn't enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because on every `.read()` call you make `content.slice(1)` and every time it copies the entire string but first character and can take a lot of time.
Try modifyin your IOStream class like this:

```
function IOstream(init){
    this.content = init;
    this.cursor = 0;

    this.read = function(){
        var tmp = this.content.charAt(this.cursor);
        this.cursor++;
        return tmp;
    };
    this.peek = function(){  return this.content.charAt(this.cursor); };
    this.write = function(str){  this.content += str; };
    this.isEmpty = function(){  return this.cursor>=this.content.length; }
}
```

I think it will solve your speed problem in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Noticed you're using loose equality. I would start there and change the == to === and see if it makes a difference.

Here is a jsperf of loose vs strict: http://jsperf.com/performance-of-loose-vs-strict-equality